# Cypher query [:RATING] relationship not working properly

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I write

`match (:Person)-[:RATING]->(m:Movie) return m`

then `(no rows)` are returned, but if I use

`match (:Person)-[r]->(m:Movie) return m`

I got the results I need.

I tried figuring out why this is happening by typing

`match (:Person)-[r]->(m:Movie) return type(r)`

and the result is `RATING`.

Can anyone give me some ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Show query to add data on which this behavior can be verified.

Comment: I am using neo4j [rest api from java](http://collabedit.com/pkxkf)

Comment: Neo4j is case sensitive - if your relationship name doesn't match the MATCH() exactly, it'll return no values.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your relationship type has some weird character at the beginning or end. To prove that theory try:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[r]->(:Movie)
WHERE type(r) <> 'RATING'
RETURN r
```